# BeautifulSoup, how to stop executing at certain tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

HTML I'm parsing:

```
<h2 class="tabellen_ueberschrift al">Cards</h2>
<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th class="al" colspan="3">CA Osasuna</th>              
        </tr>
                                                            <tr class="hell">
        <a href="example.com" class="fb s10" title="Sisi">Sisi</a>
        </tr>
                                                            </td></table>

<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th class="al" colspan="3">FC Barcelona</th>                
        </tr>
        <a href="example.com" class="fb s10" title="Busquets">Busquets</a>
        </tr>
                                                            </td></table>
```

I'm trying to count all instances of `a` tag however I need to do this sepatarely for each football team. So when it encounters 2nd `<table class="...">` the counter needs to start counting from 0 (I mean there must be two separate counters).

So far I only managed to come up with code that does the counting but sums it together. So I have only one and same counter.

I'm struggling how to tell Python where to stop and introduce the 2nd counter.

I'm not copyting in my code because up to the point where I'm stuck it's very straightforward. Any ideas greatly welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count per table:

```
for table in soup.find('table', class_='tabelle_grafik'):
    count = len(table.find('a'))
```

You do need to *do* something with each count, of course. Store them in a dictionary, print them, add them to a list, etc.

Storing them in a per-club dictionary example:

```
clubs = {}

for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='tabelle_grafik'):
    club_name = table.find('th', class_='al').text
    count = len(table.find_all('a'))
    clubs[club_name] = count
```

Comment: that's cool. I missed your assistance over the weekend Martijn :) thx

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Sorry, from time to time I indulge in having a bit of a life outside of Stack Overflow.. :-)